# iLike conditions on Non String Atrributes

Tags: grails

I am implementing a filter feature in a grails controller using the criteria builder. On my view I have:

```
<g:form action="list">
    <label for="cost">Cost</label>
    <g:textField name="cost"/>
</g:form>
```

And in the controller:

```
def list() {
    def query = {
        if(params.cost) {
            ilike('cost', "%${params.cost}%")
        }
    }
    def model = [projectInstanceTotal: Project.createCriteria().list(query)]
    if(request.xhr) {
        render(template: "grid", model: model)
    }
    else {
        model
    }
}
```

So I would like the filter to work like an ilike statement, but the problem is that cost is being stored as a Float.

Is there any way to get the criteria builder to treat the column as a String?

Note: I would like to implement this behavior for Date datatypes also.

Comment: How would you do that in SQL? Keep in mind that this isn't really magic - it's just layers on top of SQL queries.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks Burt. I guess sometimes Grails feels like magic ;) will see if I can persuade the client into using gt or lt.